# Custom SharePoint Footer at the bottom of the content using SPFx Extension

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, footer, spfx, spfx-extension

I have created a footer component in SharePoint Online using SPFX extension application Customizer. The footer is automatically created fixed because of the bottom placeholder, but I need it to be located at the bottom of the page as it is disturbing the visibility of the content. Is there any workaround for that?

Thank you!

I've applied margin-bottom to the Footer div by calculating the SPCanvas Height but it is uncertain. Sometimes it leaves more space or sometime it overlaps the content.

Comment: Check [this thread](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4375) and footer extensions code [here](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/tree/master/solution/src/extensions). let me know if it helps!